# Displaying images from MySQL database in JSF datatable

Tags: mysql, image, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have MySQL database which stores images in a `blob` column. I would like to show them in a PrimeFaces `<p:dataTable>`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Why did it not work? What is your exact error? Have you tried displaying it simply on a page instead of in a table?

Comment: possible duplicate [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360710/how-to-display-images-from-database-in-jsf)

Comment: @Aquillo : yes, i tried but it seems that Primefaces tag `<p:graphicImage>` needs an url to the image and it doesn't accept to stream the blob from the database

Comment: Try this http://java.dzone.com/articles/dynamic-images-primefaces

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`<p:graphicImage>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dynamicImage.jsf) to display images stored in a `byte[]`, regardless of the `byte[]` source (DB, disk file system, network, etc). Simplest example is:

```html
<p:graphicImage value="#{bean.streamedContent}" />
```

which refers a `StreamedContent` property.

This has however a pitfall, particularly when used in an iterating component such as a data table: the getter method will be invoked twice; the first time by JSF itself to generate the URL for `<img src>` and the second time by webbrowser when it needs to download the image content based on the URL in `<img src>`. To be efficient, you should not be hitting the DB in the first getter call. Also, to parameterize the getter method call so that you can use a generic method wherein you pass a specific image ID, you should be using a `<f:param>` (please note that EL 2.2 feature of passing method arguments won't work at all as this doesn't end up in URL of `<img src>`!).

Summarized, this should do:

```html
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    <p:column>
        <p:graphicImage value="#{imageStreamer.image}">
            <f:param name="id" value="#{item.imageId}" />
        </p:graphicImage>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The `#{item.imageId}` obviously returns the unique idenfitier of the image in the DB (the primary key) and thus *not* the `byte[]` content. The `#{imageStreamer}` is an application scoped bean which look like this:

```java
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ImageStreamer {

    @EJB
    private ImageService service;

    public StreamedContent getImage() throws IOException {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
            // So, we're rendering the HTML. Return a stub StreamedContent so that it will generate right URL.
            return new DefaultStreamedContent();
        } else {
            // So, browser is requesting the image. Return a real StreamedContent with the image bytes.
            String imageId = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("imageId");
            Image image = imageService.find(Long.valueOf(imageId));
            return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(image.getBytes()));
        }
    }

}
```

The `Image` class is in this particular example just an `@Entity` with a `@Lob` on `bytes` property (as you're using JSF, I of cource assume that you're using JPA to interact with the DB).

```java
@Entity
public class Image {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY) // Depending on your DB, of course.
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    private byte[] bytes;

    // ...
}
```

The `ImageService` is just a standard `@Stateless` EJB, nothing special to see here:

```java
@Stateless
public class ImageService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Image find(Long id) {
        return em.find(Image.class, id);
    }

}
```

#### See also:

- [Display dynamic image from database with p:graphicImage and StreamedContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage/)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Richfaces, you can use [a4j:mediaOutput](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_mediaOutput.html) component to stream the blob from a bean.

If that's not the case, I'm afraid I'm not familiar with Primefaces. If it doesn't provide any component for that you need a way of generating a URL that points to a servlet that returns the blob. That way you can use `h:graphicImage` with that auto-generated URL.

Comment: That's it, unfortunately i'm working with Primefaces and it doesn't provide this kind of component like RichFaces. I found tutorials which suggest to define a Servlet to return the blob like you said...i just post the question to find if it is possible to do that in another way. Thanks any way :)