# CSS Background Image From Database

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

How can I use an image from a database as a CSS background-image?
I can get an image from the resource library (file), but not the DB.

```
<h:outputStylesheet>
   body {
      background-image:url("#{resource[imageBean.getImage().getUrl()]}"); 
   }
</h:outputStylesheet>
```

resource[imageBean.getImage().<strike>getUrl()</strike>

Is there a way I can get the URL of the image that is in the imageBean?

I display DB images using an application scoped bean: 
[Displaying images from MySQL database in JSF datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934663/displaying-images-from-mysql-database-in-jsf-datatable)

Comment: I have stored image in database as `blob` and for displaying I used image servlet (very similar to BalusC solution). On page it is displayed via `graphicImage` like this `<h:graphicImage value="/imageservlet" style="border:0;" />`. It is not CSS solution, but it works fine for dynamic images in JSF application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a normal [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

```
@WebServlet("/image")
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private ImageService service;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Image image = service.find(request.getParameter("id"));
        response.setContentType(image.getContentType());
        response.setContentLength(image.getContent().length);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(image.getFilename(), "UTF-8") + "\"");
        response.getOutputStream().write(image.getContent());
    }

}
```

```css
body {
   background-image:url("#{request.contextPath}/image?id=#{bean.imageId}"); 
}
```

#### See also:

- [Load images from outside of webapps / webcontext / deploy folder using <h:graphicImage> or <img> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-images-from-outside-of-webapps-webcontext-deploy-folder-using-hgraphi)

Answer (score 1):

With no response for 9 months I assume there is no clean way of doing this.

**Workaround using jQuery:**

Get the image from the DB via a bean and hide it with css:

```
<p:graphicImage styleClass="backgroundImage" style="display:none;" value="#{imageBean.image}">
    <f:param name="imageID" value="12" />
</p:graphicImage>
```

Then get the path to the image and set the background-image property:

```
<script>
    if ($('.backgroundImage')) {
        var bgImageSrc = $('.backgroundImage').prop('src');
        $('body').css("background-image", "url(" + bgImageSrc + ")");
    }
</script>
```

Any improvements or suggestions are welcome.